# I am trying to figure out how to make this shape using only css

Tags: css, flexbox, css-selectors

[image: This is the shape i want to make using only css].

I am trying to create this shape on css but cant seem to figure it out.
I know i can create a rectangle and just insert circles with the same color as background. But im looking for a way to create this shape only modifying its border properties.

I have tried changing border top and bottom left and right but still can figure it out.

First try:

```
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0B2429;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}`


Second Try:

  `width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #0B2429;
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;`
```

Comment: Can you show the code for what you have tried?

Comment: _"But im looking for a way to create this shape only modifying its border properties."_ - other than by using a border-image that provides those curves, I don't know how that could work. Any border-radius applies from the "inside to the outside", but you want it the other way around. Using an SVG as mask instead would probably make the most sense here.